# SwiperJS with ionic angular - Cannot find module 'swiper/angular' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I am trying to setup swiper.js in my ionic angular project. (Using the [ionic documentation])(https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/slides)

When trying to import the module I get the error 'Cannot find module 'swiper/angular' or its corresponding type declarations.

When checking the node package there is no angular folder in the swiper package.

---

- Swiper: 9.0.1
- Node: v14.19.1
- Angular 14
- ionic: 6

Using the [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/slides)

---

`npm i --save swiper`

in app.module.ts I get the error when trying to import the swiper module:

`import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';`

[Screenshot of code line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiyEO.png)

The contents of the swiper node package:

[Screenshot of swiper folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIkOz.png)

Comment: You need to add the SwiperModule in the module your going to use it in, not in the app.module.

Answer (score 0):

Swiper Version 9 doesn't have support this. They stopped supporting angular in an 'angular' way.

The recommendation is to use Swiper elements, which requires some re-learning of swiper.

Follow the links through this page to get set up.
https://swiperjs.com/angular