# ionic2-calendar Error: Module not Found: Angular is not exported from package Swiper

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic2-calendar

I updated the package of my project

- Ionic + angular to generate app for IOS and Android
- Ionic: 7
- Angular: 16

Since this recommendation

> ion-slides was deprecated in v6.0.0 and removed in v7.0.0. We
> recommend using the Swiper.js library directly.

I migrated to the last version of [swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper)(version= 9.3.2)

But after update package.json and run `ionic build` I got this issue

```
./node_modules/ionic2-calendar/fesm2020/ionic2-calendar.mjs:8:0-37 - Error: Module not 
found: Error: Package path ./angular is not exported from package 
/Users/admin/Projects/<name_project>/node_modules/swiper (see exports field in 
/Users/admin/Projects/<name_project>/node_modules/swiper/package.json)
```

I reviewed `node_modules/swiper` and I did't find a path to angular
And checking the code of ionic2-calendar  I see that they try import swiper/angular

```
import * as i3 from 'swiper/angular';
import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular'
```

Checking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75396956/2399444)  it looks like Swiper Version 9 doesn't have support to Angular and we need to migrate to the new way to use swiper in angular. I did that in my code but in the third part code like ionic2-calendar  I didn't do that

What is the recommendation in this case? Should I downgraded the version 9 and use the version 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded Swiper from version 9 to [Version 8.4.7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper/v/8.4.7) that works for me

The last version of [ionic2-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-calendar) was updated 4 month ago almost the same Date of the update of Swiper to version 9, so probably to use  the last version of Swiper we nee to wait for a new update ionic2-calendar
[image]